# Can I have two side panels, one left and one right?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a nice wide screen, and in VS Code I would like some more room for both my file explorer and my code outline. So it would be nice if I could have two panels with in one the explorer and in the other the outline. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Indeed, not possible, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/49923.

Comment: ...too bad. There should be a law that makes using my screen space efficient mandatory.

Comment: It is an experimental feature now: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329503/836330.

Answer (score 2):

[image: put Outline into a second Side Panel]

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329503/836330 This is in Stable v1.64.

---

Then `View/Appearance/Show Side Panel` or use the icon in the upper right as shown in the demo.  That will open up a second side panel (on the opposite side of your Side Bar, the Side Bar is the panel which typically holds the Explorer view for example).

You can drag various views like the `Outline` view into this second "Side Panel".