# Visual Studio Code: change debug panel's font size and font family and debug console input as well

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, font-size

Is there a way to change the debug panel's font size and appearance in VS Code? I'm referring to the side panel where variables and their values are showed when debugging a program.
Note that I want to change only its font size, not that of the entire editor.

I've come across other similar questions here in Stack Overflow, but the solutions provided required to change the zoom level of the *entire* editor (and thus of the debug panel too), then adjust the editor's font size. However, as I mentioned before, that's not what I'm looking for. I've searched through the settings but couldn't find anything at all. To me, it seems like a very basic feature for a text editor to have, so I can't believe there's no way to do that.

I'm using VS Code 1.40.1 on Linux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would assume the ability to change the debug's views' font/fontSize is coming as part of the ability to move those views to the Panel (See [VS Code move debug tab (left panel) to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333905/vs-code-move-debug-tab-left-panel-to-bottom)).

Added:

`debug.console.fontSize`

`debug.console.fontFamily`

`debug.console.lineHeight`

Previously, the size didn't apply to the debug console input.  To be fixed in v1.45, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90714 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#notable-fixes.**strong text**

Answer (score 13):

- Paste these into your settings.json file USER section and change values to your liking.
- Note that there is no `fontWeight` for debug console, but you can state the weight in the `fontFamily`, like in the example below.
- `lineHeight` seems to be 1/3 bigger than fontSize by default, so that might be a good value to start with.

```
"debug.console.fontFamily": "Cascadia Code Light",
"debug.console.fontSize": 15,
"debug.console.lineHeight": 21,
```

Comment: Note: if lineHeight is set to 0 (zero), which is default, it's computed from fontSize. If you don't need extra line spacing, you don't need to set it.

Answer (score 3):

I have 1.55.1 on Linux and still don't see an option for font size in the debug variables panel (which, as originally asked, is not the debug console). So to adjust the font size in the debug variables panel independently, use the Zoom feature to adjust the entire VS code application, and then use the available font size settings for Editor, IntegratedTerminal and DebugConsole to unzoom those three back to the desired smaller fontsize.