# Is it possible to change the font in VARIABLES in debugger in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image: screenshot]

How can I change the font family and font size of variables in the screenshot in VSCode?

Comment: search for `font` in the settings GUI, I could not find a specific font for the Debug bar.

Comment: Is this what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991322/visual-studio-code-change-debug-panels-font-size-and-font-family-and-debug-con

Answer (score 0):

There is a GitHub issue discussing this problem:

- [Allow to change the font size and font of the workbench](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/519)

and someone has added a PR to resolve it:

- [Add settings for changing the workbench font size and font #144365](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/144365)

So maybe you need to wait for vscode to merge this function.

---

By the way, in my case,

because the font in **variables** use the default font of windows10 system - Consolas.
So I choose to change the default font, using Jetbrains Mono to replace Consolas, and it works.

[image]